# Does sklearn PCA fit_transform() center input variables?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Question in the title. After calling `pca.fit(X)`, suppose I called `pca.fit_transform(new_X)`. Is `new_X` automatically centered by PCA? The documentation is unclear on this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs:

> Linear dimensionality reduction using Singular Value Decomposition of
>   the data to project it to a lower dimensional space. The input data is
>   centered but not scaled for each feature before applying the SVD.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html

`fit_transform` is just the equivalent of running `fit` and `transform` consecutively on the same input matrix. The `fit` function calculates the means for centering the data, and the `transform` function applies the mean centering using the means calculated during `fit`.

Therefore to fit on one matrix, and apply the centering parameters learnt from that matrix to another (as, for example, when applying a model learnt on a training set to a test/validation set), you would need to use `fit` and `transform` separately.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Does this mean `fit_transform` centers the input matrix, or just `fit`?

Comment: Thank you! That solved some strange behavior I've been dealing with for a day!

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, Yes, this function in sklearn centers the input matrix. Also check this link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235931/134555

Comment: Please mention your last comment in the answers too. Thanks. :)